# Legend-cell alignment in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Consider the LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=2,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1.02)},anchor=south,
            legend cell align=right},]

\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{Explanation of the legend}

\addplot[red,
        mark=o]
        coordinates{(1,1) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8) (5,12)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}

\addplot[blue,
    mark=diamond] 
    coordinates{(1,2) (2,6) (3,4) (4,7) (5,10)};
\addlegendentry{$g(x)$}

\addplot[black,
        mark=triangle]
        coordinates{(1,6) (2,7) (3,5) (4,6) (5,1)};
\addlegendentry{$h(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

whose output is shown below.One may see that although I have used `legend cell align=right` for the right alignment of legend cells, the rule applies only to the description of cells, not to their line styles. In particular, I want the blue line with the diamond in the legend to be close to its right-aligned description `g(x)`. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[legend columns=4,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1.02)},anchor=south},scale=1.25]
            
            \addlegendimage{empty legend}
            \addlegendentry{Explanation of the legend}
            
            \addplot[red,
            mark=o]
            coordinates{(1,1) (2,5) (3,7) (4,8) (5,12)};
            \addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
            
            \addplot[blue,
            mark=diamond] 
            coordinates{(1,2) (2,6) (3,4) (4,7) (5,10)};
            \addlegendentry{$g(x)$}
            
            \addplot[black,
            mark=triangle]
            coordinates{(1,6) (2,7) (3,5) (4,6) (5,1)};
            \addlegendentry{$h(x)$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]